# mod_rewrite with three parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My URL:

```
localhost/categories?DPt=MQ==&CTg=MQ==&NLs=Mw==
```

I want so:

```
localhost/product-a/departure-a/categories-a/
```

My htaccess:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteRule ^confirmation/?$ confirmation.php [NC,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ products.php?PDt2=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^/?categories/([^/]+)/?$ categories.php?DPt=$1&CTg=$2&NLs=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
 </IfModule>
```

But it does not.
What is wrong?

Comment: Those rules to don't seem to match anything you are trying to do. What is the real URL and what do you want it to look like in the browser?

Comment: products-b/departure-b/categories-b/

Comment: That is not helpful. What should it be `rewritten` to? The real URL with the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of **.htaccess** with comments inside:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   # stop rewrite if matches existing file or directory
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule .* - [L]

   # redirect trailing slash
   RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

   # confirmation
   RewriteRule ^confirmation$ /confirmation.php [L]

   # match everything except slash to product
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /products.php?PDt2=$1 [QSA,L]

   # match categories  
   RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ /categories.php?DPt=$1&CTg=$2&NLs=$3 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: return error: Not Found The requested URL /categories was not found on this server or categories.php Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.